# How I can pass initParams from a parent clip to a child clip?

Tags: javascript, donkeyclip, motorcortex

I have a parent clip and I add another clip inside it. For example:

clip.addIncident(anIncident,0);

clip.addIncident(anotherIncident,100);

clip.addIncident(childClip,200);

I would like to know how I can pass the initParams from the clip to the childClip with MotorCortexjs. The reason is that I want to use them inside the childClip, but it doesn’t work if I use them like in the clip (e.g. “@initParams.myInitParam”), without define them in the childClip.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the initial Parameters in a child clip or Clip AS Incident (CASI as we call it) you should just pass the part you want. If you want them all you should then pass them all. For example:

InitParms.js

```
export default [
  {
    name: "Default",
    value: {
      scene1: {
        website: "donkeyclip.com",
      },
      scene2: {
        title: "Programmatic Video System for the Web",
      }
    },
  },
];
```

index.js

```
export const clip = new HTMLClip({
  html,
  css,
  host: document.getElementById("clip"),
  initParamsValidationRules,
  initParams: initParams[0].value,
  containerParams: {
    width: "800px",
    height: "450px",
  },
});

const casi = new HTMLClip({
  html,
  css,
  selector,
  containerParams: {
    width: "800px",
    height: "450px",
  },
  initParams: {
    scene1: "@initParams.scene1",
  },
});
```